# Error mounting ntfs partition

Tags: mount

Sometime when i start my computer, i can't access my hard drive and the computer gives me the following message:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda3 at /media/mramaninho/Software: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda3" "/media/mramaninho/Software"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Please can anyone help me. thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 0):

If u are using  windows 8 u will have to stop the  fast startup option in windows.
You can do it start> search po bu in configuration select "choose what the power buttons do" and Click/tap on the Change settings that are currently unavailable link at the top, and then disable fast startup and restart, now can do to linux and it will mount